# Get FileUpload 's FileName When I Select Two File Using Asp.Net for C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, filenames

I Use FileUpload Control to upload file

I used allowMultiple = true that can let me select two file

Now, I want get those file's FileName.

I don't know how realize it.

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
        try
        {
            int FileCount = Request.Files.Count;

            foreach(HttpPostedFile file in FileUpload1.PostedFiles)
            {
                Response.Write(FileUpload1.FileName);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Response.Write("Fail");
        }
}
```

Comment: Please rephrase and expand your question*. It is difficult to understand what you're asking. There should also be a question mark in there somewhere..

Comment: Thanks your suggestion, code already post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected void uploadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (fileUpload1.HasFiles)
   {
       foreach (HttpPostedFile uploadedFile in fileUpload1.PostedFiles)
       {
          listofuploadedfiles.Text += String.Format("{0}<br />", uploadedFile.FileName);
       }
   }
}
```

Example: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/99bb20/upload-multiple-files-using-fileupload-control-in-Asp-Net-4/